# Estimating stationarity of evolving distribution

Tags: distributions, stationarity, change-point, structural-change

Consider a probability distribution $P_t$ at time $t \in \mathbb{N}$ which evolves in time, but is assumed to become stationary at some unknown time $t_0$, i.e $P_{t_0+1} = P_{t_0}$

To make matters worse, I do not know the actual probability distributions $P_t$, but only the emperical distributions $\hat{P}_t$ which I can extract from time series data.

My question is two-fold:

**How should I approach my problem, as stated?
That is, how can I identify the point $t$ at which the marginal distributions stabilizes?**

Comment: You focus on possible solutions, which might have brought you too far from your goal.  **Instead, ask your question.**  It seems to be, "how can I identify the point at which the marginal distribution stabilizes?" Relevant posts are not identified by the tags you have applied: they are found under "change-point" and "structural change" keywords.